# Automatic transaction fee charge based on sales amount from app referral

Tags: javascript, react-native, transactions, stripe-payments, payment

I'm building a react native app that allows companies (clean beauty brands) to showcase their products within the app (a beauty community). App users can visit the brands' website in a nested browser in our app and buy products from the brands website. I'm looking for a way to automatically get a transaction fee from the brands for sales initiated from our app (so transactions on the brand’s site where our app acts as the referrer, so our app is affiliate marketer). The majority of the brands we work with are small companies with websites on Shopify and SquareSpace, a lot of them use Stripe. Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect). The idea is that you will act as a platform and each brand will have their own Stripe account that they connect to your platform. Then in your application, you will be able to offer their products on their behalf. When a customer wants to order some products, you can charge their card, have the funds go to the Stripe account for the brand and take your own fee out of the transaction (which is called an Application Fee).

I'd recommend looking at Stripe's detailed documentation for this:

1. https://stripe.com/docs/connect
2. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/enable-payment-acceptance-guide

Comment: Thanks! What if I would like to do something like trivago, where it takes you to the hotel website to do the transaction, and the entire transaction is done on their site?

Comment: That's not really something that you can do while taking a fee unless you work this out with every provider and they all pay you a referral fee.

Comment: if I do work with every provider, how would they calculate the referral fee, would they just determine it from analytics?

Comment: That's the only way I can think of yes